# How to float: top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got the following HTML page with just a couple of DIV-elements. These elements are generated with random values for the left margin.

Additional Info: The DIV-elements in the HTML file have to stay in the given order.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box{
            height: 50px; width: 50px; border: 1px solid black; 
            text-align: center; margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box" style="margin-left: 30px">2</div>
    <div class="box" style="margin-left: 90px">3</div>
    <div class="box" style="margin-left: 120px">4</div>
    <div class="box" style="margin-left: 240px">5</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The resulting page looks like this:

[image: actual page layout]

Is there a way, to align the DIV-elemets to the top of the page with pure CSS? 
DIV-elements should stack up, if they aren't completely beside the preceding DIV. That is why element 2 and 4 are in the second row.
Since there is no 'float: top;' command, I have no idea how to achieve the following layout:

[image: desired page layout]

Since my problem is still not clear, here is another example to clarify, that the layout should work with random generated DIV-elements:

[image]

If the element does not fit beside the preceding element, it should stack up. If it fits, it should align to the top.

***If there is no way with pure CSS, a JS workaround would also be possible.***

Comment: Why don't you just use `float: left`?

Comment: Because he wants his div to float on top, look at the second picture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a float top with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847460/how-can-i-make-a-float-top-with-css)

Comment: use `display:inline` it works

Comment: Why's the second one on the second line? This hardly seems like a floating to the top?

Comment: the problem you've got is what happens when the screen gets smaller or bigger? Shrink your browser window to see what I mean. It's very unclear what you actually want.

Comment: Unfortunately my explanations were incomplete. The resulting layout should look like picture 2, that means, that DIV-elements should stack  if they aren't completely beside the preceding DIV. That is why element 2 and 4 are in the second row.
'display: inline-block;' results in an one-row solution.

Comment: @OlivierH it is not a duplicate, because the answer with columns in the linked post does not work for random margins of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call this javascript function once the page is loaded (`<body onload="float_top()">`) :

```
var top = 5; // top value for next row
var margin = 5; // space between rows
var rows = []; // list of rows
function float_top() {
    for (var c = 0; c < document.body.children.length; c++) {
        var ok = false;
        var child = document.body.children[c];
        var cr = child.getBoundingClientRect();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (cr.left > rows[i].right) {
                rows[i].right = cr.right;
                child.style.top = rows[i].top + "px";
                ok = true;
                break;
            }
            if (cr.right < rows[i].left) {
                rows[i].left = cr.left;
                child.style.top = rows[i].top + "px";
                ok = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!ok) {
            // add new row
            rows.push({
                top: top,
                right: cr.right,
                left: cr.left
            });
            child.style.top = top + "px";
            top = child.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + margin;
        }
    }
}
```

It iterates over the `div`s, keeps track of the space used by each `div` and adds "rows" when there's no more space to put a `div` in the existing rows.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/izno/9ZkJV/).

Note:

- for this to work, the `position` of the `div`s must be set to `absolute`
- the `div`s are assumed to be the same height. You'll need some tweaking if it's not the case.

Comment: Since there is no plain CSS solution, this one is the way to go! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can either apply a `float: left` to the `.box` class or set its `display` value to `inline-block`, unless there's a reason elements 2 and 4 in your diagram have to be below 1, 3, and 5.

There's no `float: top` because it's not strictly required. `div`s are `block` elements, which means that in the normal flow of the document, they appear beneath one another, according to their placement in your HTML. There's a hybrid display value that I mentioned above, `inline-block`, which has block-like qualities but displays the elements in a horizontal fashion.

If you require that certain elements on your page "float" up or down (in the every day sense of the word), you might try applying a `margin-top` to the elements that need be be lower?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `float:left;` and re-arrange `divs`

```
<table><tr>
  <td><div class="box">1</div></td>
  <td><div class="box" style="margin-left: 30px;">2</div></td>
  <td><div class="box" style="margin-left: 90px">4</div></td>
  <td><div class="box" style="margin-left: 120px">3</div></td>
  <td><div class="box" style="margin-left: 240px">5</div></td>
</tr></table>


    <style>
    table{width:100%;}
table td{
    height:120px;
}
table td:nth-child(1n){
    vertical-align:top;
}
table td:nth-child(2n){
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.box{        
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
    </style>
```

Please check jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DzAYe/1/)

Comment: Please provide some code, not only a fiddle link, to prevent future broken links.

Comment: this solution only works if you reorder the DIVs manually. In my example there could be up to a hundred random generated DIVs.

Comment: @benny.la You can achieve this by using `<table>`

Comment: @Parixit I cannot think of a solution with the <table>-hint that fits my needs. Can you give me more information on this? Remember: I cannot sort the elements, and the number of elements and the left margin of them is random.

Comment: @benny.la Please check my update. I want to say something like this.

Comment: @Parixit this still not works with random generated DIV-elements. It only works if the DIVs are alternately float to the top and bottom. Look at my initial question, I updated it with another example.

Comment: @benny.la Then probably you should go with the javascript according to your need, you do a calculation and resolve it.

Comment: @Parixit hmmm... too bad, that it is apparently not possible to do it with CSS. Anyway, thx for the ideas!